# Syntax highlighting for custom LaTeX commands

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex

I have a few custom LaTeX commands like this one, for instance:

```
\newcommand{\oeuvre}[1]{\textit{#1}}
```

I use this for titles of books and other works. Sometimes I want them to be italicized, sometimes I want them to be in quotes, so I just use this command and I can change it all at once when necessary.

Now I want Vim to highlight that command and its contents as it does with `\emph` or `\textit`, and I want to disable spelling inside it.

(So in `\oeuvre{whatver}` "oeuvre" should be highlighted the same way as "emph" or "textit", and "whatver" should be in italics and it shouldn't count as a spelling mistake.)

Based on Vim's default TeX highlighting file, I tried this in my `after/syntax/tex.vim`:

```
syn match texTypeStyle      "\\oeuvre\>"

syn region texOeuvreStyle   matchgroup=texTypeStyle start="\\oeuvre\s*{" matchgroup=texTypeStyle  end="}" concealends contains=@texItalGroup,@NoSpell

hi texOeuvreStyle       gui=italic  cterm=italic
```

But it doesn't work. The command itself is highlighted properly, but not its contents, and spelling is still enabled.

So how can I get that to work?

(I know there are similar questions here, but I couldn't adapt them to my needs, I find this syntax highlighting stuff really confusing, sorry.)

---

Edit: Ok, I figured out that if I use `syn region texItalStyle` it'll work like I want it to… I'm still curious as to why I can't define my own `texOeuvreStyle` in what seems to me is the same way it's done for `texItalStyle` in the default syntax file though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the TeX syntax is hierarchical; the default `texItalStyle` is *contained* in two clusters, `texFoldGroup` and `texItalGroup`. The former cluster is contained in the top-level regions (`texDocZone`, `texPartZone`, and so on). Without that containment, your syntax rule never has a chance to match; the toplevel regions slice up your entire document, and they only allow *contained* members to match subsets of them.

By choosing the same syntax group for your extension, you automatically fit in. If you absolutely want to define a custom syntax group, you'd have to add them into the clusters (untested):

```
syntax cluster texFoldGroup add=texOeuvreStyle
syntax cluster texItalGroupGroup add=texOeuvreStyle
```